# Cannot borrow as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable in function arguments

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

What is going on here ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%0Astruct%20Number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20num%3A%20i32%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20set(%26mut%20self%2C%20new_num%3A%20i32)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.num%20%3D%20new_num%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20get(%26self)%20-%3E%20i32%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.num%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20n%20%3D%20Number%7B%20num%3A%200%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20n.set(n.get()%20%2B%201)%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0))?

```
struct Number {
    num: i32
}

impl Number {
    fn set(&mut self, new_num: i32) {
        self.num = new_num;
    }
    fn get(&self) -> i32 {
        self.num
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut n = Number{ num: 0 };
    n.set(n.get() + 1);
}
```

Gives this error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `n` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> <anon>:17:11
   |
17 |     n.set(n.get() + 1);
   |     -     ^          - mutable borrow ends here
   |     |     |
   |     |     immutable borrow occurs here
   |     mutable borrow occurs here
```

However if you simply change the code to this it works:

```
fn main() {
    let mut n = Number{ num: 0 };
    let tmp = n.get() + 1;
    n.set(tmp);
}
```

To me those look exactly equivalent - I mean, I would expect the former to be transformed to the latter during compilation. Doesn't Rust evaluate all function parameters before evaluating the next-level-up function call?

Comment: You can find the details of the borrow-checking process [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/master/src/librustc_borrowck/borrowck).

Comment: There is an [unborrow macro](https://github.com/durka/unborrow) for a workaround, and a discussion on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/575tc7/why_does_rust_not_allow_disjoint_mutable_borrows/)

Comment: Take a look at this [blog post](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2016/04/27/non-lexical-lifetimes-introduction/). It explains the issue in depth. There are follow-up posts with more information on the problem.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2094

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This line:

```
n.set(n.get() + 1);
```

is desugared into

```
Number::set(&mut n, n.get() + 1);
```

The error message might be a bit more clear now:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `n` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> <anon>:18:25
   |
18 |     Number::set(&mut n, n.get() + 1);
   |                      -  ^          - mutable borrow ends here
   |                      |  |
   |                      |  immutable borrow occurs here
   |                      mutable borrow occurs here
```

As Rust evaluates arguments left to right, that code is equivalent to this:

```
let arg1 = &mut n;
let arg2 = n.get() + 1;
Number::set(arg1, arg2);
```

> Editor's note: This code example gives an intuitive sense of the underlying problem, but isn't completely accurate. The *expanded* code still fails even with non-lexical lifetimes, but the *original* code compiles. For the full description of the problem, review [the comments in the original implementation of the borrow checker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/c2c99463720e758d5aa0bdcea19dc5b3dd67292c/src/librustc/middle/typeck/infer/region_inference/doc.rs#L154-L262)

It should now be obvious what is wrong. Swapping those first two lines fixes this, but Rust does not do that kind of control-flow analysis.

This was first created as [bug #6268](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6268), now it is integrated into [RFC 2094](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2094-nll.html), [non-lexical-lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423). If you use Rust 1.36 or newer, NLL is enabled automatically and [your code will now compile without an error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=67a639e672349bd870a9cd4e33b255fc).

See also:

- [Why is a mutable borrow in an argument disallowed for a mutable method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60686259/155423)