# Pass struct member variables by value when calling member functions of the same struct

Tags: rust

This Rust code does not compile:

```
struct Foo {
    x: i32,
}

impl Foo {
    fn bar(&mut self, x: i32) {}

    fn foo(&mut self) {
        self.bar(self.x);
    }
}
```

It fails because of this lifetime error:

```
error[E0503]: cannot use `self.x` because it was mutably borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:9:18
  |
9 |         self.bar(self.x);
  |         ----     ^^^^^^ use of borrowed `*self`
  |         |
  |         borrow of `*self` occurs here
```

I don't understand why the Rust compiler has an issue with the above code. `x` gets passed by value, so there is no borrow occurring to any of `self`'s member variables when `bar` gets called. The `self` that bar gets is the same `self` that `foo` has, since a copy of the member variables is sent to `bar` during the function call.

I don't see any logical reason why the code violates Rust's borrow mechanics.

Comment: Related: [Cannot borrow as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable in function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41187296/155423)