# How do I convert a mutable reference to self into an immutable reference to be used as an argument for a method?

Tags: methods, reference, rust, immutability

I have following code that can't be compiled:

```
struct A {
    x: i32,
}

impl A {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, other: &Self) {
        self.x += other.x;
    }

    fn double(&mut self) {
        self.add_assign(self);
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         self.add_assign(self);
   |         ^^^^^----------^----^
   |         |    |          |
   |         |    |          immutable borrow occurs here
   |         |    immutable borrow later used by call
   |         mutable borrow occurs here
```

How to pass `self` as the argument of `add_assign`? I have tried `&self`, `*self`, `&*self` without success.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind this? If I'm not mistaken, you want to first consume `self` by taking ownership of it then mutate `self` after you've already handed it over. What is your actual goal?

Comment: You do not need to pass a self argument. It's already "passed" when you call this method on a self instance

Comment: `add_assign` is supposed to use self and generally a different variable `other` to be added. But if I want to double, I want not to duplicate my code in `add_assign` and just pass `self` as the argument to be added.

Comment: @Fomalhaut You should make an add_assign (use the trait BTW), that take self, and the true type you want to add that will implement clone or copy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## For the current version of the question

> ```
> fn add_assign(&mut self, other: &Self)
> ```

Your request is impossible.

You cannot have a mutable reference and an immutable reference to the same value at the same time. This is a fundamental aspect of Rust.

Please re-read [the rules of references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references).

See also:

- [Cannot borrow as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47618823/155423)

## For the [first version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54543522/2) of the question

> ```
> fn add_assign(&mut self, other: Self)
> ```

Your request is impossible.

You need one instance of struct `A` to call the method on and *another* instance of `A` to pass as the argument. Your type does not implement `Copy` or `Clone` or provide any equivalent methods so there is **no way** to get a second instance.

Beyond that, there's no universal way to take a mutable reference to a value and get an owned value out of it.

See also:

- [Cannot move out of borrowed content / cannot move out of behind a shared reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28158738/155423)

## Workarounds

If you implement `Copy` or `Clone`, then you can get a second value from the original and then call either of your versions.

If you implemented `Copy`:

- `(other: Self)`

  ```
  self.add_assign(*self);
  ```
- `(other: &Self)`

  ```
  let other = *self;
  self.add_assign(&other);
  ```

If only `Clone`:

- `(other: Self)`

  ```
  self.add_assign(self.clone());
  ```
- `(other: &Self)`

  ```
  self.add_assign(&self.clone());
  ```

You probably want to implement the [`AddAssign`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html) trait to provide syntax sugar. Assuming you've implemented `Copy`:

```
impl A {
    fn double(&mut self) {
        *self += *self;
    }
}

impl std::ops::AddAssign<Self> for A {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, other: Self) {
        self.x += other.x;
    }
}
```

[Stargateur's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543522/how-do-i-convert-a-mutable-reference-to-self-into-an-immutable-reference-to-be-u#comment95889445_54543522) may also be applicable, as `i32` implements `Copy`:

```
impl A {
    fn double(&mut self) {
        *self += self.x;
    }
}

impl std::ops::AddAssign<i32> for A {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, other: i32) {
        self.x += other;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I had `copy` or `clone` how the correct code would look like? Could you, please, provide a full working example of my `double` with `copy` or `clone` implementation?

Comment: With `clone` it doesn't work. The error is `immutable borrow occurs here`.

Comment: @Fomalhaut [please upgrade to Rust's 2018 Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41187296/155423).