# Defining a tree in rust

Tags: rust, tree

I am trying to create the structure for an expression tree in rust, and I'd like for it not just to work, but also be efficient (Thus the usage of ids and an array instead of walking through pointers) and also simple to create (As in, I don't want the code for a new tree to be excessively verbose).

Currently, I have something like so:

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct ExprTree {
    tree: Vec<Node>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    index: usize,
    content: String,
    lhs: Option<usize>,
    rhs: Option<usize>,
}

impl Node {
    fn new(id: usize, content: &str, lhs: Option<usize>, rhs: Option<usize>) -> Self {
        Self {
            index: id,
            content: content.to_string(),
            lhs: lhs,
            rhs: rhs
        }
    }
}

impl ExprTree {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            tree: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    fn new_expr(&mut self, content: &str, lhs: Option<usize>, rhs: Option<usize>) -> usize {
        let id = self.tree.len();
        self.tree.push(Node::new(id, content, lhs, rhs));
        return id;
    }
}
```

With the idea being that for an expression of the form "(name == Alice) && (age >= 30)" I can define a tree like so:

```
 fn main() {
    let mut tree = ExprTree::new();
    tree.new_expr(
        "&&",
        Some(tree.new_expr(
            "==",
            Some(tree.new_expr("name", None, None)),
            Some(tree.new_expr("Alice", None, None)),
        )),
        Some(tree.new_expr(
            ">=",
            Some(tree.new_expr("age", None, None)),
            Some(tree.new_expr("30", None, None)),
        )),
    );
}
```

This structure does what I want it to do: it should be very fast to traverse using a stack of ints and the code around it isn't too verbose. The problem is, I did this like I would in C++, and Rust doesn't allow me to do it, saying 'cannot borrow `tree` as mutable more than once at a time'

My questions are: Why can't I do this? I'm mutating the `Vec` inside of the tree, not the tree itself, so I don't really understand why this happens. How would I go about making this work?
Also, in a more general sense, is there a better/more accepted way of doing trees in rust?

Comment: Your question does only contain part of the code causing the problem. I also don't quite get the difference between `tree.expr` and `tree.new_expr` (both methods are missing). This makes it harder than it needs to be for us to debug your problem. Please supply a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You may also be interested in the section "Producing a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE) for Rust code" in the [Rust tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info).

Comment: Sorry, I kind of messed up the example, expr should be new_expr, but new_expr is reproduced above

Comment: [Link to rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2e208abe21b833f653bc33998ed78c8d)

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to fix it up but your version is a lot easier to read, I'll edit my question to use it

Comment: There is a crate that does it: https://crates.io/crates/socarel (I'm the author)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm mutating the Vec inside of the tree, not the tree itself, so I don't really understand why this happens.

The point of the borrow checker is to prevent you from having data races, in this case it prevents two concurrent modifications of the `Vec`. The borrow checker accomplishes this by not allowing two mutable references to the `ExprTree` that owns the `Vec` to exist at the same time, in effect making it impossible to concurrently change the `Vec`.

However, in your example, the `ExprTree` is indeed never borrowed mutably more than once. Because the example is a bit complicated, I will explain the problem using this piece of code:

```rust
    let mut tree = ExprTree::new();
    tree.new_expr(
        "&&",
        Some(tree.new_expr("name", None, None)),
        None,
    );
```

The following would happen here if this code was executed:

1. `tree` is borrowed mutably to call `tree.new_expr("name", None, None)`

   - first mutable borrow is created
   - method is executed on the first mutable borrow
   - method returns `0`
   - **first mutable borrow is destroyed**
2. `tree` is again borrowed mutably to call `tree.new_expr("name", Some(0), None)` (`0`is the value returned by the first call to `new_expr()`

   - **second mutable borrow is created**
   - method is executed on the second mutable borrow
   - method returns `0`
   - second mutable borrow is destroyed

As you can see, the first mutable borrow is destroyed before the second mutable borrow is created. So why does this not compile?

This is a known edge case that the borrow checker currently handles suboptimally (meaning it it is too conservative – it rejects sound code: Better than the alternative ;-)). See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64976570/4674154).