# Why does using a mutable and an immutable reference in the same expression involving the += operator seem to be sometimes allowed, sometimes not?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

In the below code example, I'm trying to increment the member variable `a` of the struct `X` via a mutable reference to it, in four different ways. Here, the compiler gives the following error for the line denoted by `B`:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*x` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src\main.rs:17:23
   |
17 |     *x.get_a_mut() += x.get_a(); //B DOESN'T COMPILE
   |     ------------------^--------
   |     ||                |
   |     ||                immutable borrow occurs here
   |     |mutable borrow occurs here
   |     mutable borrow later used here
```

If it is a problem to use a mutable and an immutable reference to `a` in the same expression, why does `C` and `D` compile?

```
struct X {
    a: i64,
}

impl X {
    pub fn get_a_mut(&mut self) -> &mut i64 {
        return &mut self.a;
    }

    pub fn get_a(&self) -> &i64 {
        return &self.a;
    }
}

fn my_fn(x: &mut X) {
    *x.get_a_mut() += 5; //A
    *x.get_a_mut() += x.get_a(); //B DOESN'T COMPILE
    *x.get_a_mut() += 2 * x.get_a(); //C
    *x.get_a_mut() = x.get_a() + x.get_a(); //D
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = X { a: 50 };
    my_fn(&mut x);
}
```

Comment: I ***guess*** it happens because `*x.get_a_mut() += 2 * x.get_a(); //C` is transformed to something like `let temp = 2 * x.get_a(); *x.get_a_mut() += temp;` thus `x` is no longer immutably borrowed when `x.get_a_mut()` is called; The same thing applies for `D`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [`+=` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html), you are calling something like `add_assign(lhs: &mut i64, rhs: &i64)` in case `B` and something like `add_assign(lhs: &mut i64, rhs: i64)` in cases `A`, `C` and `D`.

In case `A`, `rhs` is a constant, different from `x.a`; no problem.

In case `C`, `rhs` is a temporary (the result of `2 * x.get_a()`) and does not need to keep a reference on `x.a` to exist; no problem.

In case `D`, `rhs` is a temporary (the result of `x.get_a() + x.get_a()`) and does not need to keep a reference on `x.a` to exist; no problem.

But when it comes to case `B`, `rhs` **is** a reference on `x.a`; then this call uses both a mutable (`lhs`) and immutable (`rhs`) reference on the same data (`x.a`) at the same time, which is forbidden.

You could eventually clone `rhs`: `*x.get_a_mut() += x.get_a().clone()`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear. So it is only in the context of the sub-scope of the `+=` operator that there is a problem in terms of the borrowing rules. There is no problem with mixing mutable and immutable references in one and the same expression (as in examples `C` and `D`).

Comment: @andreasdr I wouldn't go so far as to say that "there is no problem" - there are still cases where the current borrow checker rejects otherwise valid code, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686259/mutable-borrow-in-function-argument) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023871/returning-a-reference-from-a-hashmap-or-vec-causes-a-borrow-to-last-beyond-the-s). The good news is that in most cases, and especially when dealing with `Copy` types, you can easily resolve the issue with an explicit variable or a call to `.clone()`.